# Weird repeated sequence printed to console when installing packages through conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

## My system specs:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>conda info
Current conda install:

           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.8
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.8
conda-build version : 1.21.3
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.4
   root environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
      package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.8 requests/2.12.4 CPython/3.5.2 Windows/7 Windows/6.1.7601
```

Recently when after installing or updating packages through conda and sometimes even pip the **following sequence is printed to the console**:

```
extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but @ffi.def_extern(
) was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but @ffi.def_extern(
) was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but @ffi.def_extern(
) was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but @ffi.def_extern(
) was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
... # keeps repeating
```

I couldn't tell you how many times this is repeated I'm running console2 and the the command history gets cut off after my 300 lines. I could print the whole thing to a text file if needed but I thought I'd ask first. Does anybody know what this is or how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2913

Comment: Thanks @sundance. So I guess that it's complicated fix and the answer is; people are working on it. If you wanna take a stab making a brief summary of the problem I'll mark that as the correct answer. Maybe it'll help folks with the same issue down the road.

Comment: I have the same problem at home, but not at work.

Answer (score 16):

According to [this post](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3282), you may upgrade to Cryptography 1.7 with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install cryptography>=1.7 --upgrade
```

Comment: Consider/Prefer `conda install cryptography` in case you're in anaconda and cryptography < 1.7. This just solved the problem in my anaconda installation with cryptography originally 1.4, now upgraded to 2.1

Comment: @Raf i tried to update it with conda but it still returning the error :/