# Why is installing packages with conda resulting in internal exception (out of memory / shutdown issue)?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Whenever I install a package with `conda install <package-name>` I get the following message:

> extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but got internal exception (out of memory / shutdown issue).  Returning 0.

If I install more than one package (e.g. with `conda update --all`) then I get multiple messages: apparently the same number as number of packages. I get the messages at the end of installation, and it appears as though everything is installed fine; but I am not sure.

#### System info:

The current environment is Python 3.6, and I tried to install opencv3 as talked about here: [Installing opencv 3.1 with anaconda python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787748/installing-opencv-3-1-with-anaconda-python3). Windows 10 64-bit.

#### Perhaps a related issue:

Perhaps unrelated, but I have another suspicious behaviour. Whenever I try to install a package that is not found in conda repository I get a truncated error message:

> Fetching package metadata .............
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '

#### The Questions:

I doubt I am the only one experiencing this. I tried to search for the first message, but found no real answers. I've used Anaconda before, and on other machines, without problems. I've tried to reinstall Anaconda, but the errors persist.

1. Is this really a problem?
2. What can I do about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform are you on? How did you install conda? did you install Anaconda? 1st take is remove it completely and try installing again from scratch. The problem is not normal..

Comment: Thanks, I installed Anaconda using exe-files from Continiuum. I'm on windows10, 64-bit. I tried to remove it, but seemingly not everything was cleaned. I could try that again.

Comment: I would absolutely remove it and start over and follow instructions exactly. And I think Id install Anaconda instead. It seems to be the preferred method.. And will pre-install most everything you might need. You may want to Google how to completely remove conda from windows 10 for more help..

Comment: `pip install cryptography>=1.7 --upgrade` might do the trick. Stolen from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898928/weird-repeated-sequence-printed-to-console-when-installing-packages-through-cond?

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I completely removed Anaconda and re-installed it. I realized (after looking at the old installation file I had downloaded) that the previous version was 32-bit, while now I installed 64-bit - however I'm not sure that's relevant. I already tried to upgrade ``cryptography``, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me on Win7 except that I've run the correct (64) bit version of conda. Apparently everything installs fine despite throwing those errors

Comment: Yes, that is my impression too: that except for the errors everything was working.

Comment: `conda update cryptography` fixed those error messages for me (conda 4.5.11, python 3.5, 64-bit win10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a summary of the comments thread on the question and how I solved the issue.

Suggested solutions:

- do `pip install cryptography>=1.7 --upgrade` ref [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898928/weird-repeated-sequence-printed-to-console-when-installing-packages-through-cond).
- remove and reinstall Anaconda

**Working solution:**

Upgrading `cryptography` didn't fix my issue.

After I completetly removed and reinstalled Anaconda, and all environments, the problem was fixed. Why this didn't work the first time I reinstalled Anaconda I don't know, but assumable there must have been some residual files or settings somewhere on my system.

When I first removed the installation, I discovered that indeed the 32-bit version, and *not* the 64-bit version of Anaconda was installed. However, I don't know if that contributed to the issue because [uzelusp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491991/zelusp) had the same issue on a 64-bit installation.

Comment: Uninstalling Anaconda is a VERY heavy-handed solution to this problem.  Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use "deactivate" in the command line to exit the default environment; then I used "pip install (some package name)", it worked! 
Therefore, I suppose this issue is about the environment and library.
(Hope it may help you~)

Answer (score -1):

I also got the error `NoSpaceLeftError: No space left on devices`. Then I checked the space taken by conda(See below). I was surprised that conda takes this much space. I was having multiple environments in the same machine. So, I had to use a machine which has more space.

```
$ sudo du -shc ./miniconda3/*
18M     ./miniconda3/bin
4.0K    ./miniconda3/compiler_compat
4.0K    ./miniconda3/condabin
704K    ./miniconda3/conda-meta
176M    ./miniconda3/envs
12K     ./miniconda3/etc
5.4M    ./miniconda3/include
197M    ./miniconda3/lib
12K     ./miniconda3/LICENSE.txt
2.0G    ./miniconda3/pkgs
776K    ./miniconda3/share
4.0K    ./miniconda3/shell
0       ./miniconda3/ssl
0       ./miniconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
0       ./miniconda3/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
2.4G    total
```